# htaccess rewritecondition multiple TLDs with multiple languages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on some htaccess rewrite conditions/rules for a webshop (custom framework) with a separate blog (WordPress).
The shop lives on: shop.tld/lang/ (multiple TLDs with multi-language)
The blog lives on: blog.com

We want to incorporate the blog within the webshop structure (without redirects) like:

```
# shop.*/{?lang}/blog/{category}/{?post} (where lang and post are optional)
```

The conditions & rules for categories I've got so far (for all non-dutch languages):

```
# shop.*/(lang != nl)/blog/{category} ==> blog.com/{lang}/category/{category} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?shop\.(.*)\/((?!nl).*)\/blog$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.com/$1/category/$2 [L]
```

But the 'nl' (Dutch = native) language should not be carry out to the blog URL. So:

```
# shop.*/nl/blog/{category} ==> blog.com/category/{category}  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?shop\.(.*)\/nl\/blog$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/(.*)$ https://blog.com/category/$2 [L]
```

The preferred condition/rewrite for posts is like:

```
# shop.*/{lang != nl}/blog/{category}/{post} ==> blog.com/{lang}/{post}
```

And for dutch:

```
# shop.*/nl/blog/{category}/{post} ==> blog.com/{post}
```

Furthermore, when the post/category language on the blog isn't 'nl'/Dutch, the post-titles and category-names are suffixed with -lang. For example:

```
nl: post-title-1  
en: post-title-1-en  
fr: category-name-fr
```

It would be neat if we can 'clean this up' on the shop-side. So the all look like the 'nl'-variant (SEO wise the better choice)

I can't seemed to get a match for the following URLs (regex testing again URL-string matches perfectly, but htaccess isn't):
**Categories**

```
shop.com/nl/blog/category-1 => blog.com/category-1  
shop.nl/nl/blog/category-2 => blog.com/category-2  
shop.de/de/blog/category-2 => blog.com/de/category-2-de  
shop.com/en/blog/category-2 => blog.com/en/category-2-en
```

**Posts**

```
shop.be/nl/blog/category-1/post-1 => blog.com/post-1  
shop.com/en/blog/category-1/post-1 => blog.com/en/post-1-en
```

Hope anyone of you can help me, or at least push me in the right direction.

Many thanks and my excuses for the long post.

Note: in the near future we would like all direct request going to blog.com redirected to shop.tld/lang/blog (tld depending on the user-language).
I don't know if these current redirects get in the way(/create a infinite loop) of the default WordPress main-url change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to self:
Was looking at HTTP_HOST in the RewriteCond.
But should be looking at REQUEST_URI instead.